# Intellij, how to remove or change global repository url of subversion

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij settings -> Version Control -> Subversion -> Network，click "Edit Network Options..."， the popup with global settings. I add a repository with Kongur configuration. The url contains "\", my bad. I try to delete Kongur, it is still there. But I can't change global url now. How to remove or change the url? I didn't find the way from UI. Modifying config file is also accepted.
[image]

Comment: did you try selecting "System file" tab and change url?

Comment: @Swati System file seems just a global setting for all users. Which is the same UI and setting. I leave system file empty as I don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this tab should show you the same as configured in the subversion `servers` configuration file.

If there is nothing in the file, the list is populated with all the repositories added to SVN repository browser. You could access it with **VCS -> Browse VCS Repository -> Browse Subversion Repository** action, and delete the repo from there.

Comment: Hi Dmitriy,  Browse Subversion Repository, I don't see the repository I added. I set url contains "\", which might cause this doesn't show.